# C# appending data in textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to append data into textbox using MVVM. My problem is my data is not appending. Here is my code:

**Model:**

```
//This is where the Outgoing Ports are Tapped and the data is displayed to the serial Monitor.
var rawPacket = e.Value as RawPacket;                                                     // Data recived from the port after tapped 
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < rawPacket.RawData.Length; i++) {
    sb.Append(rawPacket.RawData[i].ToString("X2"));
}
this.serialData.LuminRecevied = sb.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
```

**View model:**

```
public string LuminRecevied {
    get { return luminRecevied; }
    set {
        if (this.luminRecevied == value) {
            return;
        }
        this.luminRecevied = value ;
        this.InvokePropertyChanged("LuminRecevied");
    }
}
```

**Binding xaml:**

```
<TabItem Header="Luminaire" Name="tabItem3" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap"  FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="13" Text="{Binding LuminRecevied,StringFormat=RX: {0}}" AcceptsReturn="True" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged_1" AcceptsTab="True" />
        </TabItem>
```

Comment: I can see only LuminRecevied where is your EnergyRecevied Property

Comment: Sorry! i posted the wrong part of the code.
i edited it. its proper now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, if you want it to append, then

```
this.serialData.LuminRecevied = sb.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
```

sets LuminRecevied equal to

```
sb.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
```

You want to do this instead

```
this.serialData.LuminRecevied += sb.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
```

Note the (+=)

Comment: Hi, still not able to append data.

Comment: Hi, when you say appending data, I'm just wondering if are you able to get anything to show up at all? I.e. when you call sb.ToString(), does the text box get populated by its value?

Answer (score 1):

```
Change your code like this and try

<TabItem Header="Energy-Meter" Name="tabItem4">
    <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="13"
     Text="{Binding LuminRecevied ,StringFormat=RX: {0}}" AcceptsReturn="True"
     TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged_1" AcceptsTab="True" />
</TabItem>
```

Comment: Hi, i want my data to append in the textbox. but it simply overwrites

Answer (score 1):

Changing the property to LuminRecevied in the binding for the Text element should be enough. A simple mock up is enough to prove this:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
private string luminRecevied;

public string LuminRecevied
{
    get { return luminRecevied; }
    set
    {
        if (this.luminRecevied == value)
        {
            return;
        }
        this.luminRecevied = value;
        this.InvokePropertyChanged("LuminRecevied");
    }
}

private void InvokePropertyChanged(string propName)
{
    var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;

    if (propertyChanged != null)
        this.PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
}


public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TabControl Height="311" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="tabControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="503">
        <TabItem Header="Energy-Meter" Name="tabItem4">
            <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="13" Text="{Binding LuminRecevied,StringFormat=RX: {0}}" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" />
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="93,0,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind hookup:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    private ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = viewModel;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.viewModel.LuminRecevied += "h";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.serialData.LuminRecevied += String.Concat(
   rawPacket.RawData.Select(i => i.ToString("X2")) + Environment.NewLine;
```